# Eclipse Oxygen Not Installing Softwares

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

[image: Desktop Screen]

I have been trying to install the window builder on eclipse.

It has been on 49 percent for days.

What could i do to fix this.

See the screenshot image.

Comment: Stop it and retry?

Comment: @nitind Iv done that severally. Still the same.